# NullPointerException when inizializing arraylist through service

Tags: java, android, arraylist, service, nullpointerexception

I'm working on an application in which the user can see a list of movies. I had originally created this without a service, but am now attempting to do all database management through the service. At first I'm trying to get the list of movies from the database. However, I keep running into this exception. I'm using a Room database to store the movies.

Before moving this code to the service, I would create a static MovieDatabase and call through that on my DAO. I've narrowed down the issue and commented out any other code, so four classes remain where the issue could stem from.

My MovieDAO class which does the actual talking to the database looks like this:

```
@Dao
public interface MovieDAO {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movies")
    public List<Movie> getMovies();
}
```

I've then created an interface MovieDatabase that looks like this:

```
@Database(entities = {Movie.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class MovieDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

   public abstract MovieDAO movieDAO();
}
```

My service, MovieService looks like this:

```
public class MovieService extends Service {
    MovieDatabase db;

    private final IBinder movieBinder = new LocalMovieBinder();

    public MovieService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return movieBinder;
    }

    public class LocalMovieBinder extends Binder {
        MovieService getService(){
            return MovieService.this;
        }
    }

    public List<Movie> getMovies(){
        ArrayList<Movie> tmpList = new ArrayList<>(db.movieDAO().getMovies()); //this is line 81
        return tmpList;
    }
```

And lastly my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ArrayList<Movie> arrayOfMovies = new ArrayList<>();
    MovieDatabase db;
    MovieService movieService;
    boolean isBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        movieService = new MovieService();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            arrayOfMovies = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(SAVED_KEY);
        } else {
            arrayOfMovies = new ArrayList<>(movieService.getMovies()); //this is line 61
        }
}
```

When running the app i run into the exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.movielibrary.MovieDAO com.example.movielibrary.MovieDatabase.movieDAO()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.movielibrary.MovieService.getMovies(MovieService.java:81)
    at com.example.movielibrary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
```

Comment: You are not initialising MovieDatabase in MovieService. Get the MovieDatabase instance either by creating directly or by dependency injection.

Comment: This is not how services work. Please read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: @devgianlu Besides doing all the work on the main thread still, is the way everything is set up wrong? I wanted to test first if it even worked before moving onto the 'real' service work.

Comment: Services can't be instantiated in the code. To start a service you need to use `Context#startService(Intent)`, please read the link I provided above.